# Data not coming to API from html

Tags: angular, mongodb, api, typescript, mean-stack

I have a Form, it contains more than one textbox. I want to read value from one textbox when some event is opccur.But the case here is I want to check whether the value is coming or not to both typescript component and API. Now the value is coming to typescript component but its not coming to API, it shows the value as 'Undefined'.what's wrong with the code?

here is my code
 HTML

```
  <div class="form-group" width="50%">
  <label>visiting flat no<sup>*</sup></label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="flat" placeholder="enter 
   flat no here" 
  (input)="isn(ref2)"  required  #ref2 ngModel></div>
```

Typescript

```
isn(ref2){
console.log(ref2.value);
this.http.post('/api/request1',ref2.value, 
{responseType:'text'}).subscribe(data=>{
})
}
```

API

```
app.post('/request1',(req,res)=>{
var url="mongodb://localhost:27017/gateway";
   mongo.connect(url,(err,db)=>{
    var dbo=db.db("gateway")
dbo.collection("vstrinfo").find({'flat':req.body.flat}).toArray((err,data)=>{
    console.log(req.body.flat);
           console.log(data);
               if(err) throw err;

                    res.send(data);

               res.end();

           })
  })
   })
```

Comment: `console.log(ref2.value);` What it is printing and another thing is to have you added bodyparser middleware in the express server.  `Note: mongo connection should not be inside API call. create another config add it there.`

Comment: console.log(ref2.value); printing whatever the value i entered in textfield.. yes i added bodyparser middleware

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Http call, you have to send Object not the string.

Mongo connection should not be inside API call. create another config add it there.

```
this.http.post('/api/request1', {
    flat: ref2.value
}, {
    responseType: 'text'
}).subscribe(data => {})
```

Comment: Thank you sharma , it's working.  i'm also MEAN stack developer(FRESHER).can u share your personal contact because i'm facing so many issues.